# How can I reshape this NumPy array correctly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm needing to combine the rows in this array:

```
array([[0.        , 1.        , 0.44768612],
       [0.34177215, 1.        , 0.        ]])
```

So that the output is:

```
array([[0., 0.34177215], [1., 1.], [0.44768612, 0.])
```

But for some reason, I can't figure it out with the reshape function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the output as a list or an array?

Comment: @James An array, I forgot to add it as I wrote the desired output myself

Comment: @wwii I have a ten-minute cooldown until I can accept an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x` is your array, `x.T` will transpose it:

```
array([[0.        , 1.        , 0.44768612],
       [0.34177215, 1.        , 0.        ]])
```

becomes

```
array([[0.        , 0.34177215],
       [1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.44768612, 0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 2):

if array is `A`, just do `A.T`...

Comment: It's not `T()`, just `T`